# How to resolve error when installing Arrow package in R?

Tags: r, windows, installation, apache-arrow

I have a problem when installing the Arrow package. I get this message:

```
> install.packages("arrow")
> library(arrow)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arrow’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'arrow', details:
  call: NULL
  error: IOError: Timezone database not found at "C:/Users/nyr/Tervező/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/tzdb/tzdata"
```

What can be done? thanks! (Using Win 11)

Comment: I'm inferring from your other question that you resolved this, is that true? If so, and it's something more than "restart R", it might be useful to others if you post an answer to your question here. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I managed to solve it using the "good ol' trick", deleting R completely and then re-installing it. No problem afterwards, the Arrow package could be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the "good ol' trick", deleting R completely and then re-installing it. No problem afterwards, the Arrow package could be installed